# Yii2 : 'Trying to get property of non-object' in GridView

Tags: php, gridview, yii2

I want to ask you about using Grid View in Yii2. In my web, i want to pass parameter from controller to gridview and i use it for GET parameter.

My Controller:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM adikbinaan WHERE adikbinaan.jenjang_id = $jenjang";

    $n = count(CariAdikBinaan::findBySql($sql)->all());

    $adikbinaan = new SqlDataProvider([
        'sql' => $sql,
        'totalCount' => $n,
        'sort' => [
            'attributes' => [
                'ADIKBINAAN_NAMALENGKAP',
            ],
        ],
        'pagination' => [
            'pageSize' => 20,
        ],
    ]);

    $adik = new CariAdikBinaan();

    return $this->render('index', [
        'dataProvider' => $adikbinaan,
        'data' => $adik,
    ]);
```

My View

```
    <?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'layout'=>"{pager}\n{items}\n{summary}",
    'showFooter'=>true,
    'showHeader'=>true,
    'showOnEmpty'=>false,
    'columns' => [
        'ADIKBINAAN_NAMALENGKAP',
        'ADIKBINAAN_TEMPATLAHIR',
        'ADIKBINAAN_TANGGALLAHIR',
        [
            'label'=>'Aksi',
            'format' => 'raw',
            'value'=>function ($data) {
                return Html::a(Html::encode("Lihat"),'adikbinaan/view?id='.$data->ADIKBINAAN_ID);
            },
        ],
    ],
]); ?>
```

And i get "Trying to get property of non-object" in `return Html::a(Html::encode("Lihat"),'adikbinaan/view?id='.$data->ADIKBINAAN_ID);`

It looks like Action Column but i don't want to use it.

How do i fix it?

Comment: Could you describe your CariAdikBinaan class, pls.

Comment: Make sure that $dataprovider is declared correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`data` is an array not an object. From the [API page for SQLDataProvider](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-data-sqldataprovider.html):

> SqlDataProvider provides data in terms of arrays, each representing a row of query result.

Therefore your code should read

```
return Html::a(Html::encode("Lihat"), 'adikbinaan/view?id='.$data['ADIKBINAAN_ID']);
```